# Facebook :: renew token for test facebook user in automated tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, facebook-graph-api, junit

I need to renew the auth token I'm getting after test user is created.

As far as I understood from manual, this could be done by redirecting the browser to authentication page, and then the browser will be redirected to landing page with authentication token in query string.

This doesn't work well for automated testing, so currently I am creating test user for every test. I think this is not the right approach, so I need to create test user once and then re-use his auth token in tests.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're asking. You want to force them to re-authenticate?

Comment: I need to create a test user in facebook development console, then take his OAuth key and be able to renew this key after it's expiration.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to extend access tokens for longer time, as explained in [manual](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/)